# Do I need "...this.state" when calling this.setState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can't seem to find a consistent example of how to properly set state in React.

Say, I've got my component that has the state:

```
state = {
   propertyOne: 'abc',
   propertyTwo: 'def',
   propertyThree: 'ghi',
}
```

If I wanted to change propertyOne I would (at the moment) do:

```
this.setState({...this.state, propertyOne: 'new value'})
```

I assumed this was needed to 'remember' the other two values, however, it appears if I do not include `...this.state` the other two values still remain.

```
this.setState({propertyOne: 'new value'})
```

So, my question is, do I need `...this.state`? Why do some people on the internet seem to suggest using it?

Comment: You don't really need it. I haven't seen someone suggesting it either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The React [Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly) show, that you do not have to use `...this.state`.

In Redux and it's [reducers](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers) you would do that, to change the store.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `...this.state`. `this.setState({propertyOne: 'new value'})` is enough. Take a look at the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly)

Answer (score 2):

State updates are merged, read more here [React docs about setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-are-merged)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is YES if you use an older version of react (I think before version 16 or 15, but not 100% sure which one exactly). If you use version 16 and later, you don't have to

Answer (score 1):

In case when you directly want to update a state value, you don't need to make use of spread syntax to update state. State updates are merged automatically.

However in spread is needed when you want to update a particular state value for instance appending data to an array.

```
state = {
   data: ['1']
}

this.setState(prevState => ({
    data: [...prevState.data, 2]
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

As other have answered. `this.setState({propertyOne: 'new value'})` is correct. React will automatically copy `{propertyOne: 'abc',propertyTwo: 'def', propertyThree: 'ghi'}`. And put them in the new state of the function along with the new key and value `{propertyOne: 'new value'}`. React only updates the key specified in the `this.setState()`

Important note: If key `propertyOne` already has the value of `'new value'` React will not update the state at all. React does a key value comparison to see if the contents of`this.setState()` are the same as `this.state`. React does this to ensure the least number of updates for a component.